# REST and JSON - converting string to JSON array

Tags: java, json, rest

I'm new to JSON and REST. I'm working with a server that returns strings like these:

```
[{"username":"Hello","email":"hello@email.com","credits":"100","twitter_username":""},{"username":"Goodbye","email":"goodbye@email.com","credits":"0","twitter_username":""}]
```

I've managed to print them out as strings on the console, but now I want to convert them into a JSON array. The code I have so far returns no errors, but I don't know what to put into the constructor for the new JSON array. I've been referring to a piece of code sent to me by a colleague, in which the constructor was new JSONArray(response) but he never told me what 'response' was.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import net.sf.json.JSONArray;
import net.sf.json.JSONObject;

import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

public class NetClientGet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      try {

        URL url = new URL("http://username:password@mobile.crowdedmedia.co.uk/index.php/api/users/get_users/");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

        BASE64Encoder enc = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder();
        String userpassword = "username:password";
        String encoded = enc.encode(userpassword.getBytes());
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);

        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + conn.getResponseCode());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            (conn.getInputStream())));

        String output;
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }

        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(output);

        for (int i =0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            JSONObject row = array.getJSONObject(i);
            String user = row.getString("username");
            System.out.println(user);
        }

        conn.disconnect();

      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

      }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- use [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to format the string as JsonArray
- then traverse the JsonArray to get the values

the code sample

```
String json = "[{\"username\":\"Hello\",\"email\":\"hello@email.com\",\"credits\":\"100\",\"twitter_username\":\"\"},{\"username\":\"Goodbye\",\"email\":\"goodbye@email.com\",\"credits\":\"0\",\"twitter_username\":\"\"}]";
JsonArray jArray = new JsonParser().parse(json).getAsJsonArray();
for (int i=0;i<jArray.size();i++) {
    JsonObject jsonObject = jArray.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
    System.out.println(jsonObject.get("username"));
    System.out.println(jsonObject.get("email"));
    System.out.println(jsonObject.get("credits"));
    System.out.println(jsonObject.get("twitter_username"));
    System.out.println("*********");
}
```

Comment: I do have one question though - is there a way to get the json string without having to hard code it like that?

Comment: try the getJson function in the code sample that i gave as an answer, in the following post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11471884/need-help-android-json-currency-converter/11472677#11472677. Using that, you can download json data from external servers

Answer (score 1):

I am using gson library to manipulate json. You can download gson from [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/list). It is a very good library to handle json.
Create json parser first, it will parse the json string:

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
```

now initialize an empty json array

```
JsonArray jArray = new JsonArray();
```

Now use the parser to create json array

```
jArray = parser.parse(outputString).getAsJsonArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used org.json.simple.JSONObject and org.json.simple.JSONArray, and I hope net.sf.json.JSONArray also work same.

You should put following string format for **output** (JSONArray array = new JSONArray(**output**); )

```
 {"YOUR_ARRAY_NAME": [{"username":"Hello","email":"hello@email.com","credits":"100","twitter_username":""},{"username":"Goodbye","email":"goodbye@email.com","credits":"0","twitter_username":""}]}
```

Now this is String representation of JSONArray.